# Change the Embeded Tweets Language in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, tweets

In my Wordpress site when I embed tweets I want them to be in English because now they are on my site language or by region. I don't know. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Tweets are translated to the language it is set..

Now in your case the html tag language is set to your regional language, to get the tweets in English, you should specify the language:

Code:

```
<article lang="en">
  <!-- embedded script -->
</article>
```

The language attribute will change the language of your tweets to the one which is set.